# OrientDB, how to give a class both behavior of graph and document

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I wanna know how to (if possible) create Java classes which have both the behaviour of:

```
Orient Document (transactions, queries, crud, traverse)
Orient Graph (properties, fields, vertices, edges, links)
```

Could You kindly redirect me to the correct issue/discussion or code-examples?

best regs

Answer (score 2):

Every time you work with OrientDB Graph API, you can always accessing to the underlying Document Database API, so you can mix usage of both.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Java class and the DB is a Graph DB you can do/will have what you posted above.
I mean:
Your class will have properties, fields, vertices, edges, link ... , 
but you will can do queries (also using traverse), crud , transactions ...

With Graph API transaction begins automatically, with Document API is explicit by using the begin() method. With Graphs you can change the consistency level.

Basically Graph API is able to support all models in just one Multi - Model.

I attached some examples.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: I appologize for the off-topic, but could you please tell me, what is the code color scheme that you are using for the example screenshot? :)

Comment: I use Eclipse, theme: Dark.